# How can we access a share folder in PowerShell, I need to copy file from share folder to local machine and vice versa

Tags: powershell

I am searching for a way to access a Share Folder with path **"F:\new_host_grab"**. From here I need to copy specific file to my Local machine! Manually it accessed by entering this path **"F:\new_host_grab"** in RUN. I'm not sure how to access in PowerShell!
Or can we just directly use Copy-item Command here!!??

Thanks and Regards,
Conan

Comment: Yes, you can. Try it.

Comment: It looks like you have a drive mapping to the remote machine's shared folder already, so yes, in that case you can simply use that path `F:\new_host_grab`. However, drive mappings are personal, so another user will probably not have that F:\ mapping. The safest way is to always use the UNC path of the remote share (``\\server\share\folderpath``). Instead of the server name, you can also use its IP address.

Answer (score 0):

"F:\new_host_grab" is not a "share", its a local folder.

If you want to copy from a share, then you need to share the folder and then copy it like this...

```
$Source = "\\ServerName\ShareName\*.*" # this is the shared folder
$Destination = "C:\temp" # local folder
Copy-Item $Source $Destination # copy command
```

If you want to list the folders in the share, you can do this...

```
Set-location $SourceFolder
Get-ChildItem -Recurse
```

You can change the `$Source` and `$Destination` variables to be whatever you like (shared folder or local folder).

Does this help?